# Not all dates are captured when filtering by dates. Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta, relativedelta

I am filtering a dataframe by dates to produce two seperate versions:

1. Data from only today's date
2. Data from the last two years

However, when I try to filter on the date, it seems to miss dates that are within the last two years.

```
date_format = '%m-%d-%Y'  # desired date format

today = dt.now().strftime(date_format)  # today's date. Will always result in today's date
today = dt.strptime(today, date_format).date()  # converting 'today' into a datetime object

today = today.strftime(date_format)
two_years = today - relativedelta(years=2)  # date is today's date minus two years. 
two_years = two_years.strftime(date_format)

# normalizing the format of the date column to the desired format 
df_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['date'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime(date_format)

df_today = df_data[df_data['date'] == today]
df_two_year = df_data[df_data['date'] >= two_years]
```

Which results in:

```
all dates ['07-17-2020' '07-15-2020' '08-01-2019' '03-25-2015']
today df ['07-17-2020']
two year df ['07-17-2020' '08-01-2019']
```

The 07-15-2020 date is missing from the two year, even though 08-01-2019 is captured.

Comment: You're converting the `df_data['date']` column to string, and then trying to use the `>=` operator to compare with `two_years` which is also a string representation of a date. This won't produce the expected results, you need both the column and the `two_years` variable to be datetime types.

Comment: @TobyPetty: I think string comparison would also work, but that would require %Y%m%d format. And I would not suggest doing it since it isn't *logically* what is intended here.

Comment: Yes true if you converted to a suitable string format you could filter on strings correctly; but I would agree it would be better to remove all these unnecessary type conversions and just filter on datetimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to convert anything to string, simply work with datetime dtype. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['07-17-2020','07-15-2020','08-01-2019','03-25-2015'])})

today = pd.Timestamp('now')

print(df[df['date'].dt.date == today.date()])
#         date
# 0 2020-07-17

print(df[(df['date'].dt.year >= today.year-1) & (df['date'].dt.date != today.date())])
#         date
# 1 2020-07-15
# 2 2019-08-01
```

What you get from the comparison operations (adjust them as needed...) are boolean masks - you can use them nicely to filter the df.

Comment: It appears I have an issue where the df['date'] is stored as a str already: -- AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @Whitewater: did you try to cast to datetime? I mean like `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`?

Comment: Yes, and I get two separate errors `TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>` and `ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: date`. EDIT: I see my problem now, I forgot to add the "df" in front of ['date'] when casting to datetime

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype conversions are the problem here. You could do this:

```
today = dt.now()  # today's date. Will always result in today's date
two_years = today - relativedelta(years=2)  # date is today's date minus two years.
```

This prints '2018-07-17 18:40:42.704395'. You can then convert it to the date only format.

```
two_years = two_years.strftime(date_format)
two_years = dt.strptime(two_years, date_format).date()
```

Comment: if the OP converts `df_data['date']` to `datetime` dtype *no conversion to string* is necessary

Comment: Agree. The ideal is to use it all as datetime.

Comment: I seem to be persistantly having an issue with the df['date'] column. It's stored as a str.